# Merge [st] and [structured-text]

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request

Can the tags [st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/st) and [structured-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/structured-text) be merged? They refer to exactly the [same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_text).

The problem is that the [st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/st) tag is commonly misused because it is either mistaken for ST Electronics, or applied to a question about functions within ST_Geometry (completely unrelated) because the author didn't bother to read the tag description.

I would suggest replacing all instances of [st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/st) with [structured-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/structured-text)--if that is possible--and then eliminating [st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/st).

Comment: If it is commonly misused then replacing all instances of st with structured-text will just leave a load of stuff miss tagged unless all of these have been corrected first

Comment: I think synonymizing is the wrong move here. Perhaps [st] is a candidate for burnination?

Comment: At time of posing there were only 5 Q's with [ST] and without [PLC] that were not structured text related.  I've removed the [ST] tag from them.

Comment: I also removed [ST] from some unrelated questions.

Comment: I have also been in the habit of editing questions I come across where [st] is misapplied. But I expect that it will keep being misused which is why I requested its elimination (burnination?).